# Can't stop timer with SignalR

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I have a SignalR project where I use the `System.Timers.Timer` class to send notifications to a web page every second.

In my web page I have a text input and two buttons, one to start receiving the updates using the filter value in the text input and the other one to stop the timer.

The problem is that if a value is entered in the text input and I click the start button, I start receiving updates, which is fine, but when I  enter a new value in the text input and click the start button again I start receiving updates for the new value AND the old one.

And if I click the stop button the timer will not stop.

I tried `timer.Stop(), timer.Close(), timer.Dispose(), timer.Enabled = false` but none of that stopped the timer.

I also tried setting `timer.AutoReset = false` and then starting the timer manually at the end of the elapsed event if a Boolean variable is set to true, but the Boolean variable never changed.

My guess is that with every click on the start button it starts on a different thread which does not see any changes that happens in the main thread.

Here is the hub code:

```
public class HubClass : Hub
{
    System.Timers.Timer stock = new System.Timers.Timer();
    int id = 1;
    SqlCommand dataRetriver = new SqlCommand();
    bool getNextFeed = true;

public void Start(string user)
    {
        USERID = user;
        id = 1;


        dataRetriver.Connection = con;


        dataRetriver.CommandText = "GetData";
        dataRetriver.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        dataRetriver.Connection = con;

        param.ParameterName = "userId";
        param.Value = USERID;

        param2.ParameterName = "@id";
        param2.Value = id;

        dataRetriver.Parameters.Clear();

        dataRetriver.Parameters.Add(param);
        dataRetriver.Parameters.Add(param2);


        stock.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(stock_Elapsed);
        stock.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(stock_Elapsed);
        stock.Interval = 1000;
        stock.AutoReset = false;
        stock.Start();
    }


    public void Stop()
    {
        //stock.Stop();
        getNextFeed = false;
        //stock.Start();
    }

    void stock_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HubClass>();

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();


        dataRetriver.Parameters.Clear();

        param2.Value = id;

        dataRetriver.Parameters.Add(param);
        dataRetriver.Parameters.Add(param2);

        SqlDataReader reader = dataRetriver.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable allData = new DataTable();
        allData.Load(reader);

        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(allData);

        context.Clients.All.broadCastMessage(jsonString);


        id = id + 1;

        con.Close();

        if (getNextFeed)
        {
            stock.Start();
        }
    }
    }
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
$(function () {


        var chat = $.connection.hubClass;

        chat.client.broadCastMessage = function (msg) {

            //update html table data

        };

        $.connection.hub.logging = true;

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

            console.log($.connection.hub.transport.name);

        });


        $("#btn_filter").click(function () {

            chat.server.start($("#txt_id").val());

        });


        $("#btn_stop").click(function () {

            chat.server.stop();

        });

    });
```

Comment: When and how are you creating the timer? It seems like you're creating a new one for every request.

Comment: no the timer is initialized on the hub level i just reset its values

Comment: How *exactly* are you initializing the timer? Show your code.

Comment: One of your biggest problem is that you are connecting the `stock.Elapsed` event every time you call your `Start` method. So when you call your `Start` method the first time everything works fine, but after the second call of `Start` your event handler is called twice per iteration, after the third call three times and so on. Connect your event handler only once, maybe in the constructor.

Comment: @abto i tried unsubscribing using -= before += but still gets the two results, and it doesn't explain why i can't stop the timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hubs API Guide](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#transience):

> SignalR creates a new instance of your Hub class each time it needs to handle a Hub operation such as when a client connects, disconnects, or makes a method call to the server.
>
> Because instances of the Hub class are transient, you can't use them to maintain state from one method call to the next. Each time the server receives a method call from a client, a new instance of your Hub class processes the message. To maintain state through multiple connections and method calls, use some other method such as a database, or a static variable on the Hub class, or a different class that does not derive from Hub

In short, you're creating a *new* instance of time on each request coming to your hub, so whatever you do to it doesn't affect what you've done to the instance created in previous request. You have to use one instance per session or per application (depending on your requirements), and store it accordingly.

Comment: man you are a saver, i used a static timer and now i can stop it ans start it anytime i want, thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Dirty or Normal

Use System.Threading.Timer and use the the event Tick instead of Elapsed.
Now your timer should stop at stock.Stop();

But you can do an dirty workaround like stock.Interval = Int32.MaxValue;

Comment: the interval should be 1000 as i want the updates to be every second, and it doesn't stop at stock.Stop()

Comment: That's the point if the stop method does not work  you can set the interval to max int  and later back to 1000 when you want to resume the interval. Because an Interval of Max Int take a Few years i think your program is not supposed to run so long.

Comment: Btw. are you using System.Timers.Timer or System.Threading.Timer?

Comment: system.timers.timer, i will try your work around and let you know

Comment: it didn't work, any change i do in any variable the Elapsed function doesn't see it the same case is with the Boolean variable

Comment: Ok, use System.Threading.Timer and use the the event Tick instead of Elapsed. At System.Threading you stop the whole tread of the timer wen you call the method .Stop().